# how to install composer installing warming using windows 10

Tags: php

Some settings on your machine may cause stability issues with Composer.
If you encounter issues, try to change the following:

The Windows OneDrive folder is not supported on PHP versions below 7.2.23 and 7.3.10.
Upgrade your PHP (5.5.12) to use this location with Composer.

Please how can i fix this?

Comment: Is there anything unclear about that message? PHP 5.5.12 is horribly outdated

Comment: You fix it by installing PHP 8 (or 7.4 if you can't be on 8), because 5.5.12 is from May 2014.